# can we control memory allocation for elements in the vector array (c++)?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vector

I will give the following codes to illustrate my question:

```
class Abc
{
 public:
  Abc(std::string &a, std::string &b, int num)
  {
       pairArray_ = std::make_pair(a,b);
       num_ = num;
   }
  std::pair<std::string, std::string> pairArray_;
  int num_;
};

class Bcd
{
  public:
     Bcd()
     {
            myArray_.reserve(100);
        }
      void push_back(std::string &a, std::string &b, int num)
      {
            Abc temp(a,b,num);
            myArray.push_back(temp);
       }

  public:
      std::vector<Abc> myArray_;


}
```

A typical usage of these two classes is as follows:

```
void main()
{
  Bcd tempExp;
  std::string a;
  std::string b;
int num;
  tempExp.push_back(a,b,num);

}
```

From the codes we can see that each time we call `push_back` function from class Bcd, memory will be allocated from class Abc, and then copy it into the vector `myArray_`. The vector will handle the memory allocation for each copied `Abc` object. This can be a problem if we put the class definition in a library while the execution codes in a program when the static run-time library is employed. I was wondering how I can avoid memory allocation from the vector array. I try to avoid memory allocation for the vector by using `reserve` in the class definition. However, this `reserve` function can only handle memory allocation for the whole vector but not for its element.

Comment: Please avoid "the class".  There are 4 classes in your post, and I *cannot* be absolutely certain which one you are referring to, or if it is the same one each time.  Be explicit about which class lives in which binary, not vague.  Be definite and direct about your problem, not "this could be a problem".

Answer (score 1):

Use [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

```
 void emplace_back(std::string &a, std::string &b, int num)
 {
        // no temporary created
        myArray.emplace_back(a, b, num);
 }
```

> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is
>   constructed through `std::allocator_traits::construct`, which typically
>   uses **placement-new** to construct the element **in-place** at the location
>   provided by the container. The arguments `args...` are forwarded to the
>   constructor as `std::forward<Args>(args)....`

Comment: Why do you think this solves the "alocated in wrong instance of std library" problem?  Please be explicit.

Comment: @Yakk "alocated in wrong instance of std library"... what is that?

Comment: the OP's problem?  An executable and library statically linked against two different heaps: or at least that is what I decoded from the entrails of the post.